# mysql on ec2 linux AMI crashed occasionally

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have wordpress with mysql installed on a Amazon EC2 linux AMI with 1 CPU and 1 GB memory.

Recently, mysql has been crashing at least once or twice a week and I can't find out what is wrong.

when I run the command

> sudo service mysqld status

I get this

> mysqld dead but subsys locked

I have enabled logging by editing the /etc/my.cnf as follows:-

> [mysqld] datadir=/var/lib/mysql socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
>
> log_error=/var/log/mysqld.log
>
> [mysqld_safe] log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
>
> pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

But everytime when it crashed, I can't really identify the errors in the log file. Recent crash shows the following in the log file /var/log/mysqld.log but 
not sure if they are the logs when I have restarted mysql.

> Version: '5.6.37'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 189532097 and 189532097 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 189715563 in the ib_logfiles!
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite
>   buffer...
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback
>   segment(s) are active.
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.37 started; log sequence number 189715563
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] IPv6 is available.
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>
> 2017-12-06 12:29:53 30473 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql56/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '5.6.37'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

I have read that some insisted that 1GB of memory is not enough for wordpress. But I also have read that some says 1GB is sufficient and in fact they only uses less than 800MB for their memory, some even have less than 600MB and their site is running fine. So I am not too convince I need more than 1GB of memory.

I have created swap file for the memory and when I do

> free -m

, it shows the following:

> ```
>          total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
> ```
>
> Mem:           993        856        137          0          8      51
>
> -/+ buffers/cache:        796        196
>
> Swap:         1023        338        685

Just for your information, my website is a really really low traffic ones with average of less than 10 clicks per day, in fact, maximum would be not more than 20 clicks per day or minimum 0 clicks per day. No transactions, just purely browsing sort of website and a simple (5 fields) enquiry form.

Can anyone help to pinpoint why there is no specific error in the log file?

Is there a way to find out what is wrong with mysql?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

---

New findings in /var/log/message, I saw this in the file. Can I confirm if this means I need more memory to my ec2 instance? But why? as mentioned earlier, it is a very low traffic wordpress site. Can anyone explain?

> Dec  6 12:26:31 ip-172-31-29-103 kernel: [939492.654915] Out of memory: Kill process 25961 (mysqld) score 222 or sacrifice child
>
> Dec  6 12:26:31 ip-172-31-29-103 kernel: [939492.658743] Killed process
>    25961 (mysqld) total-vm:1336104kB, anon-rss:4676kB, file-rss:0kB,
>    shmem-rss:0kB
>
> Dec  6 12:26:31 ip-172-31-29-103 kernel: [939493.023492]
>   oom_reaper: reaped process 25961 (mysqld), now anon-rss:0kB,
>   file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
>
> Dec  6 12:26:38 ip-172-31-29-103 kernel: [939499.813569] mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24280ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_ZERO), nodemask=0,
>    order=0, oom_score_adj=0
>
> Dec  6 12:26:38 ip-172-31-29-103 kernel: [939499.820065] mysqld cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
>
> Dec  6 12:26:38 ip-172-31-29-103 kernel: [939499.822758] CPU: 0 PID: 30069 Comm: mysqld Tainted: G            E   4.9.38-16.33.amzn1.x86_64 #1
>
> Dec  6 12:26:38 ip-172-31-29-103 kernel: [939499.825371] Hardware name: Xen
>   HVM domU, BIOS 4.2.amazon 08/24/2006
>
> Dec  6 12:26:38 ip-172-31-29-103 kernel: [939499.825371]  ffffc90001dd7b58 ffffffff812fa84f ffffc90001dd7cf8 ffff88000d998000 Dec  6 12:26:38 ip-172-31-29-103 kernel: [939499.825371]  ffffc90001dd7be8 ffffffff811f4d5b ffffc90000000000 0000000000000000

Comment: Look and see if there are any earlier mysql logs that may contain information about the crash. Also look in your systems main log files to see if there is any relevant information.

Comment: @user430214 Thanks for your reply. The earlier mysql logs are one day before and the information listed is about the same.. as shown below.. so I do not think is relevant. I will check the systems main log files.

Comment: @user430214 I have checked the main log files (/var/log/message) and I saw the word "out of memory" - see the partial log file message above (I have edited the original question to include the information). But question is why does this happen to a super low traffic site?

Comment: @JessicaL  Please post your my.cnf/ini and how many concurrent users do you want to support on your AWS instance?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL stopped working because your system ran out of memory and killed the process. At the time MySQL was terminated it was using 1,336,104 KB. This is more memory than a T2.micro.

Your problem is very clearly memory usage:

- Your sever is running out of RAM as stated in your logfiles
- You are using 338 MB of swap space which also means low memory.
- For a system with such low usage, you should not be using swap space at all.

Your solution is to add more memory to your server by switching to a larger instance size. I am one of those people that find T2.micro just too small for WordPress and a database.

Comment: Would you consider posting your my.cnf/ini for us consider?